# Jasper report downloading using $http.post not working

Tags: java, angularjs, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper reporting in my application.

The steps are the basic ones,

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment;filename=report.pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(this.template)); // .jrxml file      
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.dataList);
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, beanColDataSource);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,outStream );
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"/test.pdf");// this works in any case
```

I have a form submit in the HTML page.

```
<form action="{{vm.downloadUrl}}"
  id="downloadPdf" name="downloadPdf"
  method="post"></form>
```

The js is, (this will download the pdf without a problem)

```
vm.downloadUrl = appConfig.baseUrl+'/generateReport2?data='+data;
document.getElementById('downloadPdf').action = vm.downloadUrl;
document.downloadPdf.submit(); // document.form_name.submit();
```

But when I use the below code it will download an empty pdf, although the PDF created and saved to  the local disk from `JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"/test.pdf");`

```
$http.post(vm.downloadUrl)
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log('response received :');
                console.log(response);

                var file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                saveAs(file, 'filename.pdf'); 

            });
```

What can be the issue here. Why is it downloading an empty file. I had an issue earlier similar to this and now it's handled by setting `whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"` in jrxml file.

Comment: Is the file empty but working or is the file size 0?

Comment: file size was not zero.